# why Ghost Process appears after kill -9

Tags: python, process, kill

In my Python script, I first launch a subprocess by subprocess.Popen(). Then later on, I want to kill that subprocess by `kill -9 Pid`.

What I found is that after the kill is executed, the subprocess is "stopped" because the GUI window of that process disappeared immediately. But when I perform a "ps aux" right after the kill, the same process (with same pid) is still shown in the result. The difference is the command of the process is included in a pair of () like below:

> root 30506 0.0 0.0 0 0 s000 Z+ 6:13PM
>   0:00.00 (sample process)

This breaks my process detect logical since the dead process still can be found by ps.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: why is `kill -15` not sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manual page of ps:

> Z    Defunct ("zombie") process,
>   terminated but not reaped by its
>               parent.

That means that the parent didn't do a `waitpid()` for the child that died.

Apart from waitpid(), you can avoid that by using a [double fork](http://pcapriotti.wordpress.com/2008/02/12/fighting-zombies-with-a-double-fork/) when executing the child.

Answer (score 0):

I think -9 signal lets the process to try to handle kill and spend some time housekeeping. You can try just kill the process without signal.

Edit: oh, its actually -15 signal, that lets process die gracefully. never mind.

Comment: The KILL signal can be handled, but the program will be terminated after that. If the process was doing housekeeping it would not be in 'zombie' state.

Comment: How can SIGKILL be handled? In Python, `signal.signal(signal.SIGKILL, handler)` raises a `RuntimeError: (22, 'Invalid argument')` exception on systems that support `sigaction()`. In C you can install a signal handler via `signal(2)` for SIGKILL, but it is not called.

Answer (score 0):

Zombie processes are actually just an entry in the process table. They do not run, they don't consume memory; the entry just stays because the parent hasn't checked their exit code.
You can either do a double fork as Gonzalo suggests, or you can filter out all ps lines with a Z in the S column.